# Process.Start with asynchronous redirect of both standard output and error, error bleeds into standard output

Tags: windows, asynchronous, process, .net-6.0

I have this problem in a real scenario, but as an example, I have created a very simple program. I do not know what I am doing wrong, or if this is a known problem. In any case, I could use some tips on how to get around it.
The code is as follows:

```
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process
{
    StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        Arguments = $"/C type lorem.txt",
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        WorkingDirectory = @"C:\_temp\",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
    },
};

process.OutputDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
});
process.ErrorDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
});
Console.WriteLine("Starting!");
process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
await process.WaitForExitAsync();
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
Console.ResetColor();
Console.WriteLine("All done!");
```

This is a Console application in net6, and even though I am using visual studio, I have tried it in both Command Prompt and Powershell. The 'lorem.txt' file is just a longer Lorem Ipsum text in a text file.

The problem is that I need the error output to be handled in the handler for ErrorDataReceived, and only there, and vice versa for OutputDataReceived. The real output, though, is not so clear, as illustrated by this image:
[image: Some of the text is drawn with error handler.]

Sometimes, all the text is green, meaning the OutputDataReceived handles all the text. However, sometimes it is switched in the first paragraph, and sometimes it is as in the image, the first paragraph is all red.

For me this is clearly a race condition, but I cannot find a way around it. I would have liked to pause the Start command a few milliseconds to get the Begin...ReadLine to get registered first, or run those lines before Start, but from what I can see, that is not possible.

Does anyone have any idea on how to get around this problem?

## Edit 1 / Edit 2:

This is more similar to how we tried to implement it in the real scenario:

```
//Edit 2
var arguments = "/C docker-compose pull --no-cache my-image-id"

var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process
{
    StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "powershell.exe",
        Arguments = arguments,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true, 
        UseShellExecute = false,

    },

};
process.OutputDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.Data is not null)
    {
        _log.LogTrace("{data}", e.Data);
    }
});

process.ErrorDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.Data is not null)
    {
        _log.LogError("{data}", e.Data);
    }
});
process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine(); 
await process.WaitForExitAsync();
```

The logging is done with SeriLog.
The problem is the same, though. The messages are not mixed, but all messages come as error, and none as trace.

Comment: My first guess is that they really come as error. Powershell has a much more detailed output stream model than just `stdout` and `stderr`. Have a look at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2. I'd try a little script that explicitly uses `Write-Output` and `Write-Error` to see if the problem still occurs. The source of the PS script would also be helpful. And of course the serilog config. Are you sure it's configured to even write traces? I'd try some hardcoded `_log.LogError` and `_log.LogTrace` as well.

Comment: Good point, what I tell powershell should be important. In this case it is a script for pulling docker compose images. I have added it as Edit 2 above.

Answer (score 0):

## Summary

The problem is you are writing both `stdout` and `stderr` unsynchronized to the same console. This results in several individual problems, some of them can be handled, others not. Additionally you do not handle the end of the output or error streams correctly.

## Details

### Problem 1: No Locking

The data on `stdout` and `stderr` both come in asynchronously and get written back to the console immediately. Both output handlers can - and probably are - called from different threads and therefore there's no control in which order the statements of both output functions are called.

You probably expect something like this (the event handler name is at front of the pseudo statements):

```cs
...
OutputDataReceived: Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
OutputDataReceived: Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
-- thread context change
ErrorDataReceived : Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
ErrorDataReceived : Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
...
```

But you might as well get something like this:

```cs
...
OutputDataReceived: Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
-- thread context change
ErrorDataReceived : Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
ErrorDataReceived : Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
-- thread context change
OutputDataReceived: Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
...
```

This way the `stdout` text is written, after the console color is switched back to `red`, by the intermediate output of the `stderr` text.

### Solution to Problem 1: Lock the output

To ensure that the other hander does not interfere between setting the color and writing the output, you have to use synchronization:

```cs
var lockObject = new object();

process.OutputDataReceived += (_, e) =>
{
    lock (lockObject)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }
};

process.ErrorDataReceived += (_, e) =>
{
    lock (lockObject)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }
};
```

Always remember that things like this might happen, when you access a *single* resource, in this case the `console`, simultaneously from *multiple* different threads.

### Problem 2: Multiple Sources

Apart from the problem that the output is mixed up by not locking a *single write operation*, there is of course still the problem, that *multiple write operations* from `stdout` and `stderr` mix up - only not in the middle of a now *synchnonized* single write operation, e.g.:

```cs
...
-- stdout 1
OutputDataReceived: Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
OutputDataReceived: Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
-- stderr 1
ErrorDataReceived : Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
ErrorDataReceived : Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
-- stdout 2
OutputDataReceived: Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
OutputDataReceived: Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
-- stdout 3
OutputDataReceived: Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
OutputDataReceived: Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
-- stderr 2
ErrorDataReceived : Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
ErrorDataReceived : Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
...
```

Both event handlers get called multiple times when there's output available for either of them. So the above locking just helps against corrupting a *single* write operation, not against mixing *multiple* write operations.

### Solution to Problem 2

Due to the nature of the problem of alternatively writing into the *same* `Console` from *different* sources, there's not a really nice solution to this problem.

#### Solution 2.1: Buffer the Output

To sort this out you basically only have the option to buffer one of the output streams (e.g. `stderr`) and write it to the console only after the other stream (`stdout`) finished.

Then you would get the output of `stdout` first, in green and after that the output of `stderr` in red.

The price you pay here is that you have to wait until the program finishes, before you see the `stderr` output.

#### Solution 2.2: Write to different Outputs

This is not really a solution, but rather a different approach. If you write `stdout` and `stderr` to separate output streams, e.g. two file streams you will see, that the output won't get mixed up.

### Problem 3: Handle End of Stream

As a third problem, the end of stream is not handled correctly. The indicator that the stream has finished it's output, is that the `Data` value is set to `null`. So if `Data == null` *nothing* must be done. In your case you still set the color, even when no data shall be written.

### Solution to Problem 3: Check for `null`

```cs
process.OutputDataReceived += (_, e) =>
{
    if (e.Data == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    lock (lockObject)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }
};

process.ErrorDataReceived += (_, e) => ...
```

In case of writing to output filestreams they *should* be closed in the output handler, as soon as `Data == null`. If you don't handle the `null` value correctly, the files are not closed and possibly not synced to disk. Additionally you *cannot* just close the files after the process terminated. See Problem 4 for that.

### Problem 4: Output after the Process terminated

The event handlers can - and most probably will - be called *after* you awaited the end of the process:

```
...
await process.WaitForExitAsync();
-- handler may still be called here
OutputDataReceived: Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
OutputDataReceived: Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
...
```

This is due to the fact that the output handling is done in the *calling* process, not in the *called* process. Whenever the *called* process writes some output, the *calling* process takes over and processes the output. Only at the end of that processing a call to the `OutputDataReceived` handler is made.

As there might still be output in the pipeline *after* the *called* process terminated, the `OutputDataReceived` will also be called *after* the *called* process terminated. Now, if the *calling* program terminates before that, some of the output may be lost.

### Solution to Problem 4: Wait for the End of Stream

To solve this problem, the end of both streams has to be waited for. Essentially this boils down to waiting until both output handlers receive a `null` value, as stated above.

Some concurrency mechanism should be used to wait for the end of both output streams, before the main program terminates. This could possibly be a `ManualResetEvent` (Careful, that's a low level system event, not a C# event). See the code below for an implementation.

## Solution

The final program might look like this:

```cs
public static async Task TestOutputRedirection()
{
    var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process
    {
        StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = $"/C type lorem.txt",
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WorkingDirectory = @"C:\_temp\",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
        }
    };

    var lockObject = new object();
    var stdOutTerminated = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    var stdErrTerminated = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    process.OutputDataReceived += (_, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // do your own cleanup here, e.g. if writing to a file
            stdOutTerminated.Set();
        }
    };

    process.ErrorDataReceived += (_, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // do your own cleanup here, e.g. if writing to a file
            stdErrTerminated.Set();
        }
    };

    Console.WriteLine("Starting!");
    process.Start();

    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

    // wait for the process to finish
    await process.WaitForExitAsync();

    // now wait for both outputs to terminate
    WaitHandle.WaitAll(new WaitHandle[] { stdOutTerminated, stdErrTerminated });

    // now proceed with resetting the console
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.ResetColor();
    Console.WriteLine("All done!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very extensive answer!
However, it is not the full problem. I realise I did not state the problem very clearly, and as I have set it up, it is not apparent. Writing to the same console from async is not what is done for real, of course. I made a test where I have two totally different string buffers, and the problem is the same there; there are some text written in the error channel.
The main problem is that there is text written to the error at all! The command "type <file.txt>" is just printing whatever is in a text file. It should not generate any errors.

Comment: Well even though `type` is not printing anything on stderr, the callback still gets called, at least with with `null` to indicate the end of the error stream. So you should check for that and possibly ignore it. To determine why it mixes up things with two different streams, the original code would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
I will come back with better code when I get back to work after the vacation.

Comment: Added an edit in the original question.

Comment: Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netframework-4.0, the termination events should no longer be necessary as of .NET framework 4.0.  Given that WaitForExitAsync didn't exist until .NET 5, I expect they are not necessary here.

Comment: @TimSparkles: You are talking about the `ManualResetEvent`s? From the docs it looks indeed that they can be omitted. But I remember vaguely, that even though the process' output streams have been drained and closed after `WaitForExitAsync` returns, that does not necessarily mean they _have been sent to the callback_. They could still slumber in some internal buffer so waiting for the buffer events makes sure that the remaining data is processed by the callback before the main process terminates.

Comment: Hmm that's interesting.  I wonder if the buffer flush inside Process synchronously blocks on the FooDataReceived event handlers...  I mention this because I just encountered a bug in our Process.Start wrapper library code where we hang indefinitely waiting for the ManualResetEvent to signal if the process to be spawned never initializes its stdout or stderr streams.  I was originally going to fix this by initializing the events as set, resetting them when data arrives, and setting them when the stream ends but ended up just deleting the ManualResetEvent code.

Comment: Looking through https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/AsyncStreamReader.cs, it does look like WaitForExit will block until all output is processed, unless the FooDataReceived event handler throws.

Comment: Yep, that's true for the **called** process. The problem is the **calling** process. The **called** process has no means to determine, if the **calling** process has processed the output. The wait for the events wait's for the **in-process** processing of the stdout/stderr data. This is as far as I remember. I'm pretty sure I put the wait there for a reason. But You might just try it out. Grab the snippet above and try with or without the wait for the events.

Comment: Ok, I saw your prev comment after I answered the last. Your approach will of course work, if your **parent** process hangs around long enough for the output to be processed. But if you terminate right after the `WaitForExitAsync` I'm pretty sure you'll be missing some of the output. As for the non-initialized `stdxxx`, I never had this issue. Do you check, if the **child** process is created sucessfully after calling `Start()`? That check is missing in my example above, but of course that would hang the parent process, if start fails.

Comment: "When standard output has been redirected to asynchronous event handlers, it is possible that output processing will not have completed when this method returns. To ensure that asynchronous event handling has been completed, call the WaitForExit() overload that takes no parameter" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netframework-4.0#system-diagnostics-process-waitforexit(system-int32) calling  process.WaitForExit(); after process.WaitForExitAsync(); should work without ManualResetEvents.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Worth a try, but the manual event are *not* for the *called* process, they ensure that the output has been processed in the *current* process, which AFAIR was not the case, without them.

Comment: For me, personally, this is not a problem anymore. If anyone gets this problem, I can tip to use MedallionShell instead (https://github.com/madelson/MedallionShell). It takes care of most problems, so not using Process at all anymore.